# How to handle loop for delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I add pdf generation task in delayed jobs like below

```
@employe.each do |em|
        em.details.each do |detail|
          Delayed::Job.enqueue GeneratePdf.new(detail)
        end
      end
```

This works fine but it takes like 2min to loop through all the employes and their details and to complete the request.

How can I reduce this time? Or how can I add the loop delayed job as well. My current generate pdf class

```
class GeneratePdf < Struct.new(:detail)
  def perform
    filename =  detail.id.to_s
    pdf = EmployeDetailsPdf.new(detail) #this generates a pdf
    pdf.render_file(filename + ".pdf")
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you not pass the employee inside the delayed_job and loop inside the perform action in GeneratePdf?

Comment: yes but in that case whole loop run at once and all pdfs are generated at a time, since whole thing is treated as just one job. Its no help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I assume your `@employe` variable should be called `@employees` and stores just that: several employees

You generally should only pass the id of an object to a job. The job will query the database to retrieve the employee. It does not matter if that takes a bit longer, that's what the job is here for.

Like that, you pass the major work load to the job:

```
# some_controller
@employees.pluck(:id).each { |id| Delayed::Job.enqueue(id) }

# generate_pdf_job.rb
class GeneratePdf < Struct.new(:id)
  def perform
    employee = Employee.find(id)

    employee.details.each do |detail|
      pdf = EmployeDetailsPdf.new(detail)
      pdf.render_file(detail.id.to_s + ".pdf")
    end
  end
end
```